# update array of objects using useEffect in React Hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, algorithm, ecmascript-6, react-hooks

I have the following array that include objects using `React`, this array display the users fields data in a specific page.

What is the right way to update this component using `useEffect`, specifically the array on load of the page before data are rendered, to include:

## new element to push in the array

(on load of the page)

```
userData.splice(3, 0,
        {
          key: "gender",
          label: "DFR",
        },
    );
```

## Initial Array

```
  const userData = [
    {
      key: "first_name",
      label: "XYZ",
    },
    {
      key: "last_name",
      label: "XYYZ",
    },
    {
      key: "username",
      label: "ABC",
    },
    {
      key: "age",
      label: "ABCC",
    },
    {
      key: "nationality",
      label: "EDP",
    },
  ];
```

I have tried the following but for some reason it wont work:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    userData.splice(3, 0,
        {
          key: "gender",
          label: "DFR",
        },
    );
  }), [];
```

P.S: As you can see, i don't intend to use `push`.

Comment: Could you explain why you don't want to use `push`?

Comment: @Ezrab_ i am using `splice` instead because i want the data to be displayed at a specific position, also i need that logic to be triggered on load of the page

Comment: I didn't completely understand what you want to do. You want to modify the initial array and use the new value BEFORE the component has rendered initially? If that is so, you can't do that with a hook, as hooks are run after components are already rendered. The effect of the useEffect hook will present itself AFTER the initial rendering.

Comment: Also, are the items you want to insert into the array available to the component or are they fetched from somewhere?

Comment: @zhulien thats correct, what you described is exactly what i was trying to accomplish, also the new item is mentioned above in the post. not fetched from elsewhere.

Comment: @JohnD If that so, check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the better way is to use ES6 spread syntax.

```js
useEffect(() => {
    userData = [...userData,{key: "gender",
          label: "DFR"}]
    );
  }), [];
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes cause you just update directly in the variable userData. If you want React rerender you should use setState

```
    const [userData, setUserDate] = useState(initialData)
    
    useEffect(() => {
        setUserDate(userData.splice(3, 0,
            {
              key: "gender",
              label: "DFR",
            },
        ))
   }), [];
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use an effect for that (actually, quite on the contrary - **you shouldn't**).

`useEffect` is a hook that gets called **after** the initial rendering of the component.

In your case, you just simply need to generate a set of fields in the form of an array to be used for the component rendering. If those fields are **static**, **not changing** and **are always the same for the given component**, you just encapsulate them in a normal variable in the component itself and then you use them in the rendering. As simple as that.

On the other hand, if they're non-static and different instances of the same component can have a different set of fields - calculate them in the parent component and pass them down as `props`.

If, however, the fields can change dynamically throughout component's lifetime, you need to use state. Once again, you simply assign the calculated field set to the initial state and you're done.

In all of those cases, you'll get your fields ready before the render phase has happened.